# Such great photos?

Tags: word-choice

I'm not sure if it's correct to say:

> Such great photos.

It seems right to me, but I'm not getting any results from Ngram Viewer. Any alternatives?

Comment: There are no verbs in your quote. What is it that makes you doubt it - other than Ngram results!

Comment: I guess I see that more as a 'string' than a proper sentence. This is why I've checked in Ngram, I want to use it that way: "Hello (friend), thank you for the mail. Such great photos! blah blah..."

Comment: The phrase is properly constructed and idiomatic. In short, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

That is a mystery to me. "Such great pictures" yields results, but both "such great photos" and "such great photographs" cause the message "Ngrams not found: such great photos, such great photographs".

I cannot imagine anything is wrong with that seemingly common phrase. It is grammatical and idiomatic in English.

Maybe just a quirk of Google's process. "such great music", "such great ideas", "such great pictures", and even "the dangerous of" [sic] all display results.

Comment: Yes: but I would add to the answer that, as a sentence fragment, this is informal English.